# C - Read from Input File, Convert Test Score to Letter Grade, Calculate Average, Extract Minimum and Maximum of each test

Tags: c, file

I'm a rookie programmer trying to figure this exercise out:

**Summary** : Write a program that determines letter grades for students in a class, using control flow, arrays, pointers, structures, disk files, and error conditions in C Programming.

**Description** : Program accepts two command line arguments.The first argument is the name of a disk file that contains the names of students, and their scores, separated by commas, followed by one or more spaces. Each line contains score for one student. The second argument is the name of an output disk file. The program creates a new output file using that name. Write the grade information of all student whose information was read from the input file in a sorted order into the output file. Write one line per student in the output file. Write the name of a student and the letter grade they received in a formatted style in an output file. The format of data in the input file is fixed but the number of student at the compiling time is unknown. Name of input and output file could be anything and only known during the compiling time. Besides writing to output file, display the average scores along the minimum and maximum scores for each test in the screen.

**Could anybody help and point to the mistakes?** I'm using Xcode for this, and this always pops up : "Control may reach the end of non-void function". It's in "// METHOD 4: CONVERTING FROM STUDENT TOTAL SCORE TO LETTER GRADE" at the end. I've triple check to make sure all curly braces are correct, but it seems not.

Here below is my code so far. Would be great if somebody can help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STUDENTS 100
#define STRING_LENGHT 255
#define TEST_SCORES 7
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0



// METHOD 1 : REMOVING EXTRA WHITE SPACE
typedef struct {

    char name[STRING_LENGHT];
    char letterGrade;
    int scores[TEST_SCORES];

} STUDENT;

char *trimString(char *string)
{
    char *end = NULL;

    while (isspace(*string)) string++;

    if (*string == 0)
        return string;

    end = string + strlen(string) - 1;

    while (end > string && isspace(*end))
        end--;

    *(end + 1) = 0;

    return string;

}

// METHOD 2 : READ FROM INPUT FILE
int loadStudents(char *filename, STUDENT students[MAX_STUDENTS], int *numStudents)
{
    FILE *inFile = NULL;

    char *tokenizer = NULL;
    char line[STRING_LENGHT];
    char token[STRING_LENGHT];

    int i = 0;

    inFile = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        printf("FAIL! Cannot open %s\n", filename);
        return FALSE;

    }

    *numStudents = 0;

    while (fgets(line, STRING_LENGHT, inFile))
    {

        trimString(line);
        tokenizer = strtok(line,",");

        strcpy(token, tokenizer);
        strcpy(token, trimString(token));
        strcpy(students[*numStudents].name, token);

        for (i = 0; i < TEST_SCORES; i++)
        {
            tokenizer = strtok(NULL, ",");
            strcpy(token, tokenizer);
            strcpy(token, trimString(token));
            students[*numStudents].scores[i] = atoi(token);

        } 

        (*numStudents)++;

     } 

    return TRUE;

} 


// METHOD 3 : CALCULATING INDIVIDUAL STUDENT SCORE
double calculateGrade(int scores[TEST_SCORES])
{
    double weights[] = { 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.20, 0.15, 0.25 };
    double grade = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < TEST_SCORES; i++)
    grade += scores[i] * weights[i];

    return grade;

} 

   // METHOD 4 : CONVERTING FROM STUDENT TOTAL SCORE TO LETTER GRADE
char calculateLetterGrade(double grade)
{
    if (grade >= 90)
    return 'A';

    if (grade >= 80)
    return 'B';

    if (grade >= 70)
    return 'C';

    if (grade >= 60)
    return 'D';

    if (grade <= 59)
    return 'F';

} // ***THE PROBLEM IS HERE *** //

// METHOD 5 : CALCULATING STUDENT GRADE
void calculateStudentGrades(STUDENT students[MAX_STUDENTS], int numStudents)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        students[i].letterGrade = calculateLetterGrade(calculateGrade(students[i].scores));
}

// METHOD 6 : SORTING STUDENT NAME ALPHABETICALLY
void sortStudents(STUDENT students[MAX_STUDENTS], int numStudents)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    STUDENT temp;

    for (i = 0; i < numStudents - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < numStudents; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(students[i].name, students[j].name) > 0)
            {
                temp = students[i];
                students[i] = students[j];
                students[j] = temp;

            } 
        }         
    }

}

// METHOD 7 : WRITING STUDENT LETTER GRADE TO OUTPUT FILE
int writeGrade(char *filename, char *inputFilename, STUDENT students[MAX_STUDENTS], int numStudents)

{
    FILE *outFile = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    outFile = fopen(filename, "w");

    if (!outFile)

    {
        printf("Error: failed to open %s\n", filename);
        return FALSE;

    } 

    fprintf(outFile, "Letter grade for %d students listed in file %s\n\n\n Here is the class average:\n\n", numStudents, inputFilename);

    for (i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        fprintf(outFile, "%s%c\n", strcat(students[i].name, ":"), students[i].letterGrade);

    fclose(outFile);
    return TRUE;

} 


// METHOD 8 : CALCULATING INDIVIDUAL TESTS AVERAGE
double calculateAverage(STUDENT students[MAX_STUDENTS], int numStudents, int scoreCategory)

{
    double sum = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        sum += students[i].scores[scoreCategory];

    return sum / numStudents;

}


// METHOD 9 : BUBBLE SORT AND EXTRACTING MINIMUM SCORE OF EACH TEST
int findMinimumScore(STUDENT students[MAX_STUDENTS], int numStudents, int scoreCategory)

{
    int min = -1;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        if (min == -1 || students[i].scores[scoreCategory] < min)
            min = students[i].scores[scoreCategory];

    return min;

} 


// METHOD 10 : BUBBLE SORT AND EXTRACTING MAXIMUM SCORE OF EACH TEST
int findMaximumScore(STUDENT students[MAX_STUDENTS], int numStudents, int scoreCategory)
{
    int max = -1;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        if (max == -1 || students[i].scores[scoreCategory] > max)
            max = students[i].scores[scoreCategory];

    return max;

}
```

Comment: The message itself is just telling you the compiler cannot guarantee a return based on the code you have written. Even though you cover the range of `0-100` in your conditionals, the compiler doesn't know that. It is just looking at `calculateLetterGrade` and saying "*What the hell happens if nothing is matched??*" You can either just add a `return 0;` at the end standalone, or you can make the last `if (grade <= 59) ... else return 0;`. (you must really like to type, `calcltrgrd` would work fine `:)`

Comment: I actually rather not type but being a newbie I just write what I know. Would love to know more about how to write better code.

Comment: Writing better code comes with experience. There is no language that requires as thorough an understanding as C (assembly excepted) and there is no language that gives you more low-level control and speed than C (same exception). As for writing in the correct style, see e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf)

Comment: Awesome thanks David!

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: if none of the `if` conditions are true, then the function doesn't return anything.  If you know that the tests are exhaustive (at least one of them *must* be true), then you don't need the last test (if all of the others are false, the last, being the only one left, must be true), and can just have the final `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Scott is correct in his explanation, but I will go into more detail with code.

```
char calculateLetterGrade(double grade)
{
    char g = 'F';
    if (grade >= 90)
    g = 'A';
    else
    if (grade >= 80)
    g = 'B';
    else
    if (grade >= 70)
    g = 'C';
    else
    if (grade >= 60)
    g = 'D';

    return g;
}
```

This approach I think is easier, but you had a logic error.

If the grade is 85 then it will end up being a 'D' as it is greater than 60.

You could reverse, but by using the else, the first one that matches it skips the rest, so now an 85 is a 'B'.

And having one return just makes it easier to read. I don't like having lots of paths out of a function, just as a preference.

Comment: Hey, thank you guys! Yes it's a logically and I understand the reasoning behind it now. I was thinking like a human not like a compiler. It makes sense to start with an "F" and filter it. Now it works but... there's still an issue :  "_main", referenced from: Link command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation). Sorry have no idea what it means. Help?